# Line and column contexts in PowerBI measures?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to replicate a calculation originally made in Excel, using PowerBI and although I have read some documentation about context calculation in measures, I am struggling to get the results.

My table would like as the one below

| Date | Weight | Calculated_measure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 1 | 0 |
| 01/02/2020 | 3 | 31 |
| 01/03/2020 | 3 | 147 |

Dates are in dd/mm/yyyy.

The idea is the following for the calculated measure:

1. For each line I compare the current “Date” value with all other “Date” values and make a subtraction.
2. If the result of the subtraction is greater than zero, I keep the result. Otherwise, I set the result to 0.
3. Then I multiply the results by the weight

To illustrate the calculation of the third line:
(01/03/2020-01/01/2020)*1 + (01/03/2020-01/02/2020) *3 + (01/03/2020-01/03/2020) *2
=60 * 1 + 29 * 3 + 0 =  147

The formula in Excel for the first line, for example:
= {
SUMPRODUCT(
IF
(
(A2-$A$2:$A$4)>0;
(A2-$A$2:$A$4);
0
)
;  $B$2:$B$4
)
}

Thank you. Understanding this code will help me a lot to learn context filters in PowerBI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusing bit in DAX is how to know which row context to use.

You can use the [EARLIER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/earlier-function-dax) function to move back from the sumproduct row context to the earlier original row context and define your measure like this:

```
CALCULATED_COLUMN = 
SUMX (
    Table1,
    IF (
        EARLIER ( Table1[DATE] ) > Table1[DATE],
        EARLIER ( Table1[DATE] ) - Table1[DATE]
    ) * Table1[WEIGHT]
)
```

If you don't want to worry about remembering how EARLIER works, you can use a variable to define the original row context as a constant and use that in the iterator:

```
CALCULATED_COLUMN = 
VAR RowDate = Table1[DATE]
RETURN
    SUMX (
        FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Date] < RowDate ),
        ( RowDate - Table1[DATE] ) * Table1[WEIGHT]
    )
```

In the above, I applied a filter instead of using an IF. This is typically more efficient when applicable.

---

**Edit:** In the above, I was thinking in terms of a calculated column. For a measure, the situation is slightly different and OP's comment below is the appropriate adjustment:

```
MEASURE =
VAR RowDate = SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[DATE] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        FILTER ( ALL ( Table1 ), Table1[Date] < RowDate ),
         ( RowDate - Table1[Date] ) * Table1[WEIGHT]
    )
```

The SELECTEDVALUE is needed since row context doesn't exist for a measure and ALL is needed to apply the sum-product to the whole table instead of just the part in the filter context.

Comment: Thank you, Alexis!

I had to make a few adaptations for the formula to work (to use SELECTEDVALUE to capture one specific value instead of all the values in the column and added an ALL to filter) but I could understand the logic and implement. Thank you very much.

-----------------
Dax_2 = 
VAR RowDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[DATE])

RETURN 
            SUMX( 
                FILTER( 
                        ALL(Table1),
                         Table1[Date] < RowDate
                       ), 
                   (RowDate - Table1[Date]) * Table1[WEIGHT]
              )
-------

Comment: Ah, good point. The table setting had me thinking of calculated columns. I've edited my answer to clarify this for future readers.